# Difficulty setting up a 'post' route in an express server issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm attempting to validate that my client can post info to it's server. I've set up this 'route' in my Express server.

```
// server.js  this is the server for the PvdEnroll application.
// 

var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    mongoose = require( "mongoose" ),
    app = express();

// static file directory for default routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// create Express-powered HTTP server 
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
console.log("Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000/");

// set up a post route in the server
app.post("/selections", function (req, res) {
  console.log("data has been posted to the server!");
});

app.post("/selections", function (req, res) {
  console.log("Some data has been posted to the server from app.js");   
})
```

The client uses this file:

```
 var main = function () {
"use strict";

$.getJSON("../data/checkBoxesA.json", function(checkBoxTxt) {
    checkBoxTxt.forEach(function (data) {
        var $checkbox = "<input type ='checkbox' name = " 
            + data.label  + "id = 0 UNCHECKED/>";
      $(".enroll_actions").append($checkbox);
      $(".enroll_actions").append(' ' + data.label + "<br/>");
      $(".enroll_actions").append(' ' + data.note + "<br/>");
      $(".enroll_actions").append('              '+ "<br/>");           
    });
}); 
$(".comment-input").on("click", function (event) {
    console.log("Hello World!");            
    // here we'll do a post to our selections route
    $.post("selections", {}, function (response) {
        console.log("Client says - We posted and the server responded!");
        console.log("Response from server :", response);        
        console.log("STUBB1");
    });     
});
  console.log("STUBB2");
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

In the Chrome console I'm getting:

```
POST file:///Users/*******/Projects/r_PE/app/PvdEnroll/client/html/selections    net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

A path is being sought but a tutorial's example (which works!) and is structurally identical to mine(?) **uses a name i.e. "selections" to establish a route between client and server**.

I'm running the server on my Mac using Virtual Box and Vagrant.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Did you try navigating to the client html via your node web server instead of loading the file locally?

Comment: Is that static-server definitely allowing pass-through to additional routes? Typically you want catch-alls like static server after your custom routes. Even if the static-server does call next when a file is not found, putting it after your custom routes safer (and faster) since this way you can't accidentally block a route by having a file or directory with the same name.

Comment: Also, I notice that your console output shows a local file path. If you're running this as a server, even though it's local, it shouldn't be file://, it should be http:// ... what's going on there? Are you sure you're accessing it at localhost or are you just opening the local html file directly? [edit: I just noticed that @mscdex already pointed this out]

Comment: I relocated the reference to the static file directory in the server.js and it made no difference

Comment: On restarting the server the log message is now "POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/html/selections 404 (Not Found)."

Answer (score 0):

> On restarting the server the log message is now "POST 127.0.0.1:3000/html/selections 404 (Not Found).

Okay. This is some helpful information!

Basically, your file structure is more or less this (some file names will be different, just look at the general structure):

- Node.js code (including main `.js` file and the `module.json`)
- `client`: a folder for your static content

  - `html`: a folder

    - `index.html`: the file you are currently using

Anyway, `jQuery.post()` is fed a *relative path* (as apposed to an absolute path). That means that, based on the location of where the code was, it will "guess" the location of the file.

That means that it was trying to find a route at `[locahost:port]/html/selections` when your server is listening at `[localhost:port]/selections`! You'll need to have jQuery post to `/selections` instead of just `selections`.

For more information, [this blog post is helpful](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) (relative paths work the same in Javascript/CSS). The helpful snippet:

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts    there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep    moving forward